# How do I make my line fit better and neater?

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I am trying to make a simple plot with the following code.

```
eta = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)
R = c(0, 0.647058807, 0.864035125, 0.992063541, 0.996376783, 1)

p = as.data.frame(cbind(eta, R))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(p) + 
geom_point(aes(x = eta, y = R), size = 3) +
geom_smooth(aes(y=R, x=eta), method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

I get a plot like the following:

[image]

Can the geom_smooth function take in arguments to change the line width or line type? Is there a way to get a better fit so that the curve looks like a nice continuous function like the one below?

[image]

Comment: If your question is only about the 'look' of the line you might use `geom_xspline()` from the `ggalt` package instead of `geom_line()`. See https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt#splines

Answer (score 4):

You can set a custom formula in `stat_smooth`. Following your example, if you want to fit a 4th order polynomial you can use

```
ggplot(p, aes(x = eta, y = R)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~ poly(x, 4), se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Edit: Adding an equation that has an asymptote at 1.0. This is a little trickier as it requires solving using a nonlinear approach.

```
ggplot(p, aes(x = eta, y = R)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', 
              formula = y ~ 1-exp(-k*x),
              se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Although it's convenient for plotting, `stat_smooth` makes it tricky to access the fitted model. You can fit outside of `ggplot` using the `nls` function directly, then make predictions using `predict`.

```
# Fit model
fit_nls <-nls(R ~ 1-exp(-k*eta), data=p) 

# Predict model
df_pred <- data.frame(eta = seq(0,1.1,.01)) %>%
  mutate(R_pred = predict(fit_nls, newdata = .))

# Plot it
ggplot(p) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = eta, y = R), size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = df_pred, aes(x = eta, y = R_pred))
```

Comment: Is it possible to ensure that the fitted line does not go over R = 1?

Comment: You could add `ylim(c(0,1))` (as in `ggplot() + ylim(c(0,1))`) and it won't fit values over 1, but this will drop data from the fit.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `span` of the fit to make it more or less smooth. You can also change the line width with `size` and type with `linetype`:

```
ggplot(p) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = eta, y = R), size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(
    aes(y=R, x=eta),
    method = "loess",
    se = FALSE, 
    span = 0.9, 
    linetype = "dashed",
    size = 0.5)
```

**EDIT** here's the plot:
   [image]